# I need slider for Android like slider in Playstore

Tags: jquery, html, slider, hybrid-mobile-app, user-experience

I am about to build a hybrid Android application. I need a horizontal slider like a slider in Playstore which is easy to scroll right and left. I tried using `slick.js` but it is still not as easy as the slider in Playstore. Any one know what slider to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one i Know of slideMenuLibrary [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

But its old and there's also [FantasySlide](https://github.com/mzule/FantasySlide)

I've Used SlideMenu and its cool.. and can still be used in your projects

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Always summarize the content of your links, so that your answer will stay useful in case the link target gets removed, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers